# Python Discord bot, I want the user to input two names and combine it into one and search the json data

Tags: python, python-3.x

> {"draw":0,"recordsTotal":1261,"recordsFiltered":1261,"data":[{"id":"1","ClassID":null,"Name":"Default
> Sword","Description":"Default weapon for
> Legends!","Type":"Sword","Element":"None","File":"items/swords/GasparianBlade.swf","Link":"GasparianBlade","Icon":"iwsword","Equipment":"Weapon","Level":"1","DPS":"25","Range":"10","Rarity":"3","Quantity":"1","Stack":"1","Cost":"0","Coins":"0","Crystal":"0","Sell":"1","Market":"1","Temporary":"0","Upgrade":"0","Founder":"0","Vip":"0","Staff":"0","EnhID":"1","FactionID":null,"ReqReputation":"0","ReqClassID":null,"ReqClassPoints":"0","ReqQuests":"","QuestStringIndex":"-1","QuestStringValue":"0","Meta":null,"Color":"ffffff"},{"id":"2","ClassID":"1","Name":"Vagabond","Description":"A
> Vagabond that doesn't have much of experience, we must keep moving and
> learn more about our
> Adventure!","Type":"Class","Element":"None","File":"CyberPeasant.swf","Link":"CyberPeasant","Icon":"cclass","Equipment":"ar","Level":"1","DPS":"25","Range":"50","Rarity":"3","Quantity":"1","Stack":"1","Cost":"0","Coins":"0","Crystal":"0","Sell":"1","Market":"1","Temporary":"0","Upgrade":"0","Founder":"0","Vip":"0","Staff":"0","EnhID":"1","FactionID":null,"ReqReputation":"0","ReqClassID":null,"ReqClassPoints":"0","ReqQuests":"","QuestStringIndex":"-1","QuestStringValue":"0","Meta":null,"Color":"ffffff"},{"id":"3","ClassID":null,"Name":"Balrog
> Blade (Beta)","Description":

This is my data and I created a python discord bot that when the user input Name : Deafult Sword it output's the id: 1 but in discord it only accepts the first word and outputs not found "Deafult" how to make the python script take these both "Deafult Sword" and search the json data and output the id: 1

```
@bot.command()
async def item(ctx, item):

 data = "* data *"

 info_dict = json.loads(data)

 # Taking user input
 user_input_name = item

 # Find and print the ID if Name matches
 for entry in info_dict['data']:
     if entry.get("Name") == user_input_name:
         await ctx.send(f"Name : {item} - ID : {entry['id']}")
         break
 else:
     await ctx.send("ID not found. try writing full name."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referencing [official discord.py documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html).
Discord bot commands take the whitespace-separated words after the command name as separate arguments.
To make use of a word with spaces in between, you should quote it like such: `/item "Default Sword"` => `Default Sword`. As a note of warning, if you omit the quotes, you will only get the first word like you described in your issue: `/item Default Sword` => `Default`.

Since positional arguments are just regular Python arguments, you can have as many as you want:

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, arg1, arg2):
    await ctx.send(f'You passed {arg1} and {arg2}')
```

If you want to take all the arguments (whitespace-separated words), you can use Python's `*args` feature like such:

```
@bot.command()
async def item(ctx, *args):

   data = "* data *"

   info_dict = json.loads(data)

   # Merging the args into one string
   user_input_name = " ".join(args)

   # Find and print the ID if Name matches
   for entry in info_dict['data']:
       if entry.get("Name") == user_input_name:
           await ctx.send(f"Name : {item} - ID : {entry['id']}")
           break
   else:
       await ctx.send("ID not found. try writing full name.")
```

I hope this solves your problem. Have a nice day!